# INNER JOIN tables not counting the results

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables (*ads_users* & *ads_users_tracking*). I used [INNER JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) to combine those tables together because they have matching values in both tables.

The *ads_users_tracking* table has a column called "**count_hits**" and both tables have a column called "**group_set**"

I'm trying to add together **count_hits** and GROUP BY **group_set**. So the result should the number 3 (all count_hits added together with the same *group_set* equals 3) but I keep getting the following error below

"*Query 1 ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'COUNT(count_hits) FROM ads_users_tracking INNER JOIN ads_users' at line 1*"

I have tried many different times to get this to work. I've been on stackoverflow for hours, so I reaching out for some help. The INNER JOIN just confuses me. Any help would be much appreciated!

**Sql query:**

```
SELECT *, COUNT(count_hits) FROM ads_users_tracking INNER JOIN ads_users ON ads_users.id_tracking = ads_users_tracking.userid_track_code GROUP BY group_set
```

---

**ads_users table**
[image]

---

**ads_users_tracking table**

[image]

---

Comment: You need a comma after `*`.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the reply. I missed that. I updated my code but now i'm getting "Query 1 ERROR: Column 'group_set' in group statement is ambiguous"

Comment: You have a `group_set` column in both tables. You need to add a table prefix to indicate which one to use.

Comment: Got it! ads_users_tracking.group_set. It looks like that worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: Okay, I thought it was working. It seems to be only returning me the results of the two different groups. It's not counting (adding) all the count_hits together and grouping those counts hit together by the group_set...

Comment: @Barmar Figured it out! Thanks again for your help. I removed `COUNT(count_hits)` and replaced it with `SUM(count_hits) AS count_hits`